# StackExchange Android App login failed

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, login

Yesterday I downloaded StackExchange App from Play Store and installed it to my brand new Samsung Galaxy S5, but it didn't recognize my login and password pair. So it failed to login.

I checked with the same login and password from my computer it worked as well. I did it in new Browser session that I was needed to login first. So I can confirm there is something strange in there...Did anybody have the same issue? Any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Try now! We had an issue for around 8 hours yesterday which made it so logging in via e-mail / password failed. This was fixed on the backend side so it should work on your device *right* now.

Comment: Yes, it works now, I am writing from the App now. Thank you for the fastest attention.